# How to use the value of a global variable to determine the control flow of a function running in separate thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port

In my first project with serial communication I am trying to implement a procedure where a function in a background thread listens on the serial port for a ready signal. When a ready signal is received it updates a global variable to a True value so that another function will start.

Below is a simplified version of the logic, but I cant get it to work. Instead of running concurrently the two threads it seems like it is still running consecutively

```
import threading
import time


global CONS
CONS = False
print(CONS)

def timeout(state,my_timeout):
    _time = 0
    while _time < my_timeout:
        if state:
            print(state)
                    print('Signal received, returning True to start another function')
            return bool(state)
        _time += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(_time)
    else:
        print('Timeout occured: Ready signal not received within %s seconds', _time)
        return False

def smallmeth():
    time.sleep(2)
    global CONS
    CONS = True
    print(CONS)
    return CONS


t1 = threading.Thread(target=timeout(CONS,5))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=smallmeth)
threading.enumerate()
# t1.setDaemon()
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

The output I get when running this is this:

```
False
1
2
3
4
5
Timeout occured: Ready signal not received within 5 seconds
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=timeout(CONS,5))
```

Here you call the function `timeout` and then you pass the result as target for the new Thread. So `timeout` is executed before `t1` is created. If you want to pass arguments to the thread target, do it like this:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=timeout, args=(CONS,5))
```

Also you never use the global variable in `timeout`. So the result will still be the same even after you make the correction mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This fixes the issue of running threads concurrently.. I thought that using `CONS` as an argument in the `timeout()` function would be enough, but I see that it isnt.. A temporary fix is to put `state = CONS` into the while loop, but that is not going to fly in the long run when I want to check for multiple constants.